# Calling the Next category link on an archive page - Wordpress

Tags: php, functions

I've been working on creating a link in my header, should say "see *enter next category name here*"

I've been using this code, found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99513/how-to-get-next-previous-category-in-same-taxonomy/116227#116227) (I would comment again to ask directly on that question, but I'm not allowed)

```
    function get_adjacent_category($category_slug,$taxonomy,$type){
global $wpdb;
if($type=="next"){
    $operater=" > ";
    $orderby=" ORDER BY tt.`term_id` ASC ";
}else{
    $operater=" < ";
    $orderby=" ORDER BY tt.`term_id` DESC ";
}
$query="SELECT *,(SELECT `term_id` FROM wp_terms WHERE `slug`='".$category_slug."') AS given_term_id,
    (SELECT parent FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE `term_id`=given_term_id) AS parent_id
    FROM  `wp_terms` t
    INNER JOIN `wp_term_taxonomy` tt ON (`t`.`term_id` = `tt`.`term_id`)
    HAVING  tt.taxonomy='".$taxonomy."' AND tt.`parent`=parent_id AND tt.`term_id` $operater given_term_id $orderby LIMIT 1";
return $wpdb->get_row($query);

    }

    $next_category =  get_adjacent_category($slug,$taxonomy,"next");
    $previous_category =  get_adjacent_category($slug,$taxonomy,"previous");
```

and while I'm not getting an errors, it's not pulling the next category up for me.  Just a blank space.  Here's the code I'm using to call the function:

```
    <div style="float:right;">See<?php get_adjacent_category($slug,$taxonomy,"next"); ?></div>
```

Am I calling it incorrectly?  If it helps, I'm working with Thesis theme, and here's the [website](http://onesummerdayphoto.com/theblog/color-story/dark-red/) I'm working with.  I'm trying to place it on an archive page, mirroring to the "back to blog" link at the top.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You are not `echo`ing anything, and if you tried you wouldn't get what you expect because `get_row()` returns an Object by default. These are both basic PHP problems. `var_dump()` your data from the function and see if it looks right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not using the function correctly - it returns an object, and won't output anything by itself. You also need to ensure that `$slug` and your other arguments are set & have values, otherwise you'll just trigger an  error.

Personally, I'd go one step further and use the following function instead - the arguments are more flexible, and there's simply no need for custom SQL queries; you can capitalise on existing WordPress functions with the added benefit of object caching.

```
/**
 * Get adjacent category or term.
 * 
 * @link    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/137203/1685
 *
 * @param   string  $direction  "next" or "previous"
 * @param   mixed   $term       Term ID, slug or object. Defaults to current tax archive, if applicable.
 * @param   string  $taxonomy   Optional. Not required if $term is object.
 * @return  object|null
 */
function get_adjacent_term( $direction = 'next', $term = null, $taxonomy = null ) {
    if ( $term ) {
        // Bit of type checking as we want the term object.
        if ( is_numeric( $term ) )
            $term = get_term( $term, $taxonomy );
        elseif ( ! is_object( $term ) )
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term, $taxonomy );
    } elseif ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ) {
        // Default to current term object if $term was omitted.
        $term = get_queried_object();
    }

    if ( ! $term || is_wp_error( $term ) )
        return null;

    // Get all siblings of term.
    $terms = get_terms(
        $term->taxonomy,
        array(
            'parent' => $term->parent,
        )
    );

    // Find index of current term in stack.
    foreach ( $terms as $index => $_term ) {
        if ( $_term->term_id == $term->term_id )
            break;
    }

    if ( $type === 'next' ) {
        if ( ! isset( $terms[ ++$index ] ) )
            return null;
    } elseif ( ! isset( $terms[ --$index ] ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    // $index will now be the adjacent term.
    return $terms[ $index ];
}
```

And in use, at least on taxonomy archive pages, is simply:

```
<?php if ( $next = get_adjacent_term() ) : ?>

    <div style="float: right;">
        See <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $next ) ?>"><?php echo $next->name ?></a>
    </div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: You are a rockstar.  That worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Quick question, could this work for tags too?  I'm a total newb, I thought I knew how to add it in, but apparently did not.

Comment: I have added `is_tag()` to the function, so yes, will work for them too now :)